# Error Duplicate Key in mongo shard cluster

Tags: mongodb

one of our sharding part went down
Now the logs say:duplicate key: Faild to update the persistent chunk metadata for collection....
and this is some error before this:

```
2020-03-:23:15.161+0330 F - [sessionCatalogMigration-rs8_rs159e8a61] Invariant failure oplogEntry.getWallClockTime() src/mongo/db/s/session_catalog_migration_destination.cpp 246
2020-03-:23:15.161+0330 F - [sessionCatalogMigration-rs8_re8a61]

***aborting after invariant() failure
```

Comment: The error message does not mention any duplicate key error. Are you sure it belongs to your problem?

Comment: Yes
duplicate key: Faild to update the persistent chunk metadata for collection....

Comment: The actual error message would be helpful.   You say it was a duplicate key error, which would only occur on a write, but the log except you provided is an error reading a timestamp from an oplog entry while waiting for replication.  If the duplicate key was part of the "failed to persist chunk metadata" error message, that would imply it was a problem on the config server, so check that log as well.